# How to load different data in each table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, nsdictionary

I have a table view with a list of chat rooms, and I'm attempting to get a collection view of the avatars of all members in each cell.

As I have it, my function gets the required information about the members of the rooms and sets it to dictionaries in `cellForRow`:

```
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.getParticipantInfo(roomId: self.usersRooms[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].id)
                existingRoomCell.avatarView.addSubview((self.navCollectionView?.view)!)
            }
```

This is the function to grab the data from Firebase:

```
var avatarDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
var statusDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

func getParticipantInfo(roomId: String) {

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let groupRef = databaseRef.child("groups").child(roomId)
    groupRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

            for each in snapDict {

                let uid  = each.key
                let avatar = each.value["profilePicture"] as! String
                let status = each.value["status"] as! String

                // Set those to the dictionaries [UID : value]
                self.avatarDictionary.setValue(avatar, forKey: uid)
                self.statusDictionary.setValue(status, forKey: uid)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.navCollectionView?.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    print("\n\nDone\n\n")
                }
            }
            print("\n\navatarDictionary:\n \(self.avatarDictionary)")
            print("\nstatusDictionary:\n \(self.statusDictionary)")
        }
    })
}
```

I see 5 of each dictionary printed to the console (I have 5 rooms currently), so it looks like it's getting separate dictionaries for each room. However I'm stuck as to how I can specify which dictionaries are for which room, so only the members of that room show up in the corresponding table view cell.

In the collection view's `cellForItem` method for example, I set the avatars by getting all the values from the avatarDictionary into an array:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let avatars = self.roomVC?.avatarDictionary.allValues as! [String]
        navBarCell.avatarImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(avatars[indexPath.row])
    }
```

However since I have multiple dictionaries now, I don't know how to specify which dictionaries are for which room in the table. Currently it just uses one (the first, I think) `avatarDictionary` so the avatars only show up for one room in the table.

How can I approach this to have the collection view load the avatars from the correct dictionaries, and not just a single one?

Answer (score 0):

Because the Firebase call is async, I would recommend passing the `roomId` to your tableviewcell and having the cell handle loading the avatars and statuses.

For example, some pseudo code:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var roomId:String? {
        didSet {
            if let roomId = roomId {
                getParticipantInfo(roomId)
            } else {
                //clear the data and cancel any pending Firebase request
            }
        }
    }

    func getParticipantInfo(roomId: String) {
        //load your room, parse the data into your dictionaries and use the dictionary to power the collectionview datasource
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        roomId = nil
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT based on comments**

Quick question - your question mentions TableView and the variable is collectionView.  Doesn't matter for the solution, but which one is it?

I can envision 2 different approaches to storing your data.  Which you pick depends on how your actual data looks.

If avatars/status are unique to each room, and with the assumption that you have just one section, so we only need to key off of rows.  I would make a struct to hold your data, to make everything a little clearer.  Here I have an array of RowData structs, which hold the roomId and an array of Avatar structs, which hold the imageURL and status.  This way you don't have two parallel arrays or dictionaries of clearly related info.  Correct me if I am wrong with the assumption.  You now can access the avatar data with a row as index.

```
struct Avatar {
    var imageURL: String
    var status: String //eventually this is better as an enum
}

struct RowData {
    let roomId:String
    var avatars = [Avatar]()
    init(roomId: String) {
        self.roomId = roomId
    }
}

var rowData = [Int: RowData]()

func getParticipantInfo(roomId: String, row: Int) {
    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let groupRef = databaseRef.child("groups").child(roomId)
    var thisRow = RowData(roomId: roomId)
    rowData[row] = thisRow
    groupRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for each in snapDict {
                guard let imageURL = each.value["profilePicture"] as? String, let status = each.value["status"] as? String else { continue }
                let avatar = Avatar(imageURL: imageURL, status: status)
                thisRow.avatars.append(avatar)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.navCollectionView?.collectionView?.reloadItems(at:[IndexPath(section:0, row:row)])
                print("\n\nDone\n\n")
            }
        }
    })
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rowData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as RoomCell
    if let thisRowData = rowData[indexPath] {
        cell.rowData = rowData[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        getParticipantInfo(roomId: usersRooms[indexPath.row].id, row: indexPath.row)
    }
}


class RoomCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var collectionView:UICollectionView
    var rowData:RowData? {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rowData ? rowData?.avatars.count : 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
        let avatar = rowData?.avatars[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if there is a large amount of overlap between avatars in different rows, you could add a prop like `var roomIds:[String]` to the Avatar struct, and have an array of `[Avatar]`, and then filter on `roomId` to populate your rows.  The advantage of this model is that if your API returned Avatar info with multiple rows, you would effectively be caching the data across multiple rows and not have duplicate Avatar objects

Comment: The collection view class uses the dictionaries from the table view controller as the data sources: https://pastebin.com/3ft1qS1W , would I use the custom cell as the data source instead (i.e. `let avatars = self.customCell?.avatarDictionary.allValues as! [String]` instead of `let avatars = self.roomVC?.avatarDictionary.allValues as! [String]`)

Comment: I may not fully understand your original question.  I assumed that each tableviewcell displayed a unique set of async data.  Are you suggesting that this is not the case?  If you have the dictionaries as part of the tableviewcontroller, then after loading the async data, you will need to store the data and then reload the cells at the correct index paths.  If this is the correct assumption, I can model out a sample as well.

Comment: That's correct, each tableview cell displays the avatars for the members of that room - the `getParticipants` function is passed a `roomID` and it gets the avatars and statuses for the members of that room and sets them to the dictionaries. This is where I get lost - I'm not sure how to ensure that once those dictionaries are set, how the program will know to use Dict A as the data source for Cell A, Dict B as data source for Cell B, and so on. With your answer, I'm not sure if I should be removing that function and all dicts from the table view controller and moving them to the cell.

Comment: Thanks for doing this! It looks like a lot of stuff I haven't used before so I'll do my best to understand & implement it - from first look though, it looks like you suggest doing away with the dictionaries? I use those as the datasource for the collection view, so I'd have to change my collection view class quite a bit (pastebin.com/3ft1qS1W). Also, would I be trying this code in the table view controller? Just to clarify, I have a table view controller, and then I have a separate class for the collection view. Not sure if that was clear.

Comment: As for your questions in the edit, the question of mine is regarding both table and collection view - I'm trying to put a collection view in every table view cell, each with different data depending on the users in the room.